# team foundation server (TFS) in the cloud not able to delete / adjust mapping

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, workspace, azure-devops

I tried out the TFS Service with a project of mine. After I experienced some problems (probably misuse) I used VSUnbindSourceControl.exe (see: http://vsunbindsourcecc.codeplex.com/) to detach the project (locally) from the TFS, but it looks as if on the server side, the project that was uploaded, is still bound to my computer.

See image:

[image]

and the error message in the output window:

Failed To Create Mapping
The working folder G:\Quant tool DotNet4 is already in use by the workspace USER-PC;myemail@ somedomain dot com on computer USER-PC.

(I now use a different email address than the one above)

I've tried to delete the project from the server via the Source Control Explorer in VS, but the delete option is disabled. (also when I login with mldz at hotmail dot com.

I was also not able to delete the project or change it's settings via the TFS web interface.

Anyone experience with this problem and how to solve it with the new TFS in the cloud? i saw some similar problems with a normal TFS and some solutions could be done via the the team foundation administration tool, but that cannot be applied to the TFS in the cloud (AFAIK)

**Some info about trying to install TFS integration tool**

Hi,

I use VS2012 express and although I installed vs_teamexplorer.exe,

[image]

I'm not able to install Microsoft Team Foundation Server Integration Tool.

[image]

[image]

Already restarted the computer after installation and tried again. Doesn't work. Missing something?
regards,

Matthijs

Comment: It's been around longer than a couple of weeks, BTW.

Comment: hummmm...weird. I only found out after I received an email from microsoft on the 14-th of november 2012:" 
It's available now. It's Team Foundation Service, a new way for teams who care about rapid software delivery to plan and manage projects. And for teams up to 5 developers, it's free."

Comment: By the way. If you are familiar with the TFS in the cloud, can you tell my how to delete a project?

Comment: Just removed the project from the server via this tip: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFService/thread/81997146-a64f-43fb-9952-57d71542cd11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same admin tools for tfs.visualstudio. See examples. At end of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj130558.aspx article which show deletion of workspaces, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will start reading the documentation and try to solve the problem. I'll get back to you whether or not I got it working again. regards

Comment: Hi, I tried to install TFS integration tools, but bounced into some problem. Please see added comment. Hope you have a suggestion.

Comment: I am not sure why you need to install the TFS Integration Tools. I just pointed you at the article as it shows that the administration tools, such as "tf workspace /delete" work against tfs.visualstudio as well. I do not believe you need the TFS Integration Tools in your case ... but if you want to install anyway, have a look at this workaround: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2012/07/04/tfs-integration-tools-issue-this-tool-requires-the-tfs-client-object-model.aspx and read the constraints of the tools carefully before clicking the migrate button